# javascript function that returns Promise for an array

Tags: javascript, promise, iterable

I am trying to write a function that returns an array of two objects, which is a promise. The original is rather lengthy so I try to abbreviate it:

```
  function initCalc() {
    var [av, driving] = calcCarRoute(start, end, dt)

    var results = [];
    results.push(av);
    results.push(driving);
    return results;
  };

  function calcCarRoute(start, end, dt) {
    var temp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var driving = {};
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var request = {
        //some code;
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          //some code;
          resolve(driving);
        };
      });
    });
    return temp.then(function(value) {
      var driving = value;
      //some code;
      return driving;
    }).then(function(value2) {
      var AV = {};
      //some code;
      return Promise.all([AV, value2]);
    })
  };
```

However, when executing, I get the error:
`calcCarRoute is not a function or its return value is not iterable` . I feel more or less certain that the problem is with the fact that I want the return value to be an array, because my structurally identical functions that return an object works fine. I have also tried returning just `[AV, value2]` instead of `Promise.all()` in calCarRoute but that did not work either.

EDIT: to entertain some reasonable comments, I have developed a toy model. The goal of the codes below is to save the returned values of `calcFood()` in two promises, so that I can chain them for further manipulation later on.

```
initCalc();

function initCalc() {
  var [staple, meat] = calcFood().then(function([value1, value2]) {
    return [value1, value2];
  });
  var other = calcOther();

  Promise.all([staple, meat, other]).then(function([staple, meat, other]){
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(staple));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(meat));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(other));    
    }
  })
};

function calcFood() {
  var temp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve({Lunch:'Rice', Dinner:'Pasta'});
  });
  return temp.then(function(value) {
    var meat = {};
    Object.assign(meat, value);
    meat.Lunch = 'Fish';
    meat.Lunch = 'Chicken';
    return [value, meat];
  })
};
function calcOther() {
  var temp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve({Other:'None'});
  });
  return temp;
};
```

Comment: "*my structurally identical functions that return an object works fine*" - I doubt that. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: "*an array that is a promise*" - nope. The result is a promise that will fulfill with an array (in short: a promise for an array). Yes, that promise is not iterable. You have to wait for the result using `then`

Comment: I am a first-time user of stackoverflow and thanks for the reminder. Please see added toy model. Thanks!